# Multi-digit numbers in the QField attribute table

Tags: qfield

We use QField on a Samsung tablet to map birds. To do this we also need to record the number of birds seen. For this we always used the "Number" field in the attribute table and until a few months ago we were able to enter multi-digit numbers without any problems. Recently, only single-digit numbers are possible and you have to use a controller to increase the numbers, which takes a lot of time. How can we change that again? Why doesn't it work anymore?

(we do have the latest version and tried deleting the app and reinstall)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't have a solution either, but would be very interested in. Creating a "Text" field and converting it into integer later doesn't seem to be a very sensible workflow; on the other hand, entering bigger numbers into integer fields has become nearly impossible...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/266121)